# Why doesn't increasing the frequency of an induction launcher increase repulsive force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szPwPLNN4IM) about induction launchers. Uses faraday's law of induction and Lenz law to induce current into the ring causing a magnetic field in the opposite direction of the coil's, causing a repulsive force.

$emf=N\frac{ΔΦ}{Δt}$

This means that increasing the rate of change of the magnetic field, it will induce a larger emf and as a result current(cause $I=V/R$). This means there should be a greater magnetic field(cause $B=\mu0NA$)

So tested this with a basic LC oscillator circuit I had around with a piece of copper pipe(used a pipe cause of skin effect)

However, all this did was heat the pipe (very quickly and very hot), with no visible repulsion. This means large current was induced, but why wasn't there a repulsive magnetic field that would propel the copper pipe?